# Running code periodically without another thread

Tags: c, time

This is the code that I have:

```
while(1)
{
   if (fmod(get_elapsed_time(), 3.0) == 0.0)
   {
       printf("Hello World\n");
   }
}
```

The `get_elapsed_time` function returns a `double` which is the time elapsed since the program started in seconds with the milliseconds after the decimal place.

So this code should be printing hello world every 3 seconds but it doesn't and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Comparing for equality is always risky with floating point numbers, and especially when trying to measure time. For example, if you happen to call `get_elapsed_time()` at time 2.9999 and again at time 3.0001, the modulo will not be 0 for either time. And then you'll have to wait another 3 seconds before trying (and failing) again.

Comment: @user3386109 But if I cast it to an `int` it keeps printing till the next second

Comment: For amateur programs, just use Sleep() or sleep(), depending on OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run something every t seconds in C?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2049870/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point inaccuracy. Keep track of when you last printed a thing, and when the current time is >= 3 seconds of that, it's time to print more.

Something like

```
float last_print_time = get_elapsed_time();
for(;;) {
  float current_time = get_elapsed_time();
  if (current_time - last_print_time >= 3.0) {
    printf("Beep!\n");
    last_print_time = current_time;
  }
}
```

Comment: like this ? : `if (get_time_elapsed() - stored_time >= 3.0)` , `stored_time` is the time at the start of the loop  and I'm setting `stored_time` to the current time if this condition is true, I'm still not getting anything printed

Comment: stored_time needs to be initialized outside the loop and then updated only when you print stuff.